# Get the patch out of GitHub PR

Tags: github, pull-request

Some time ago I submitted PR to one of the projects I'm involved with.

That PR got some comments and I tried to follow up with them.

Now that PR became clogged with different changes and everything.

Is there  way to get the original submitted copy of the PR from the GitHub somehow and resubmit it a fresh with all corrections so that the maintainers can just grab it and push it upstream?

Comment: Just close the PR and file a new one? The original code is "the branch your PR was for", linked at the top of the PR page itself on GitHub.

Comment: Not 100% sure but a PR is a compound of commits you want to merge into another branch, so use git diff to get the .diff patch that can be applied using `patch`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I can close the PR and open a new one. But I need to recreate the code from the original PR with all the suggestions to make it a clean one.

Comment: @HernanGarcia, I can. Problem is - the branch that was used for the PR is gone now.

Comment: Then there is no PR anymore, either? You can't have a PR without a branch (although you can have a _merge commit_ for a closed PR for which the branch was deleted. In which case: look at the merge commit's parent commits and check out the one that had the changes)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, what I meant to say is the local branch is gone. PR and remote is still available

Comment: I don't understand: if the PR and branch are still up, just check out the branch from whatever remote it exists on, after making sure you have that remote in your list of git remotes? But now we're in "this is git basics" territory and you might want to search the web for a primer on using git with github.

Answer (score 0):

you can use GitHub's [compare API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits?apiVersion=2022-11-28#compare-two-commits) to get a patch by adding `.diff` to the end. The APIs format is

```
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/compare/BASE...HEAD.diff
```

For example, if you wanted the diff for a project called `example/project` between commit `abc` and the `main` branch, the URL would be

```
https://api.github.com/repos/example/project/compare/main...abc.diff
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `git diff` to generate a patch

```
$ git diff > file.patch
```

Then apply it using `git apply`

```
$ git apply file.patch
```

A Pull Request is a compund of commits that you want to merge into another branch

Check the commits IDs using `git log`

```
$ git log
```

so you'll be able to apply diff between commits

```
$ git diff commit_id1 commit_id2
```

Comment: this is all on the local machine, right? But I can't do that - the original branch I made a PR from is gone and looking at those commits is pretty ugly.

Comment: in that case you need to provide more info, provide PR url if it's publicly hosted, if not please share if it's on github or somewhere else